# Combinations of 100 feet, 100 socks, and 100 shoes

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Celia the centipede has 100 feet, 100 socks, and 100 shoes. How many orders can she
choose from to put on her socks and shoes? (She must put a sock on foot i before putting
a shoe on foot I.)

---

I have read on the other questions ([Putting socks and shoes on a spider](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3091953/putting-socks-and-shoes-on-a-spider))
that the formula should be $\frac{200!}{2!^{100}}$

However, isn't this approach considering that every sock has its own corresponding shoe? i,e. sock $x$ wants shoe $X$ only.

What if any sock can take any shoe?

What if I don't care about the order of putting them on but only on the number of combinations of sock and shoe. Would it be simply $100! * 100!$ in that case?

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3091953/putting-socks-and-shoes-on-a-spider

Comment: It would be extremely helpful if you could put a *link* to "the other questions" which give you the formula $\frac{200!}{2!^{100}}$, so that we could check whether "this approach" is "considering that every sock has its own corresponding shoe" (as you claim) - or not. I am inclined to say that this formula should be valid if all socks are identical to each other, and all shoes are identical to each other, and you are counting the number of *ways to order the operations* (such as "put on a sock on leg $53$", "put on a shoe on leg $72$" etc. - all $200$ of them).

Comment: @StinkingBishop I have edited the question and I have included the link suggested by user1001001

Comment: I have a big problem with that other question. The question was asked on Jan 29, 2019 (9:09 UTC). The (accepted) answer that you are probably looking at was posted the same day at 9:43 UTC. However, the sentence "socks and shoes are **distinguishable**" was added only the next day, Jan 30, 2019 (11:16 UTC). Thinking of moving goalposts! I still think the accepted answer treats all socks and shoes are **indistinguishable** and only counts the number of operations, as I said in my previous comment.

Comment: @StinkingBishop your thought is right  , i  indicated it in comment in given link , maybe edition can be done over it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order does not matter , then you answer is correct. Assume that we have $100$ empty different boxes (we said them legs) , we want to put $100$ different candies and $100$ different balls. How many psossible ways are there ? First , put the candies by $100!$ , after that put the balls by $100!$ ways (the order of putting candies or balls firstly does not matter) . Then, there are $100! \times 100! $ ways.

If the order matters,as well , as you wrote $\frac{200!}{2^{100}}$ , then $$\frac{200!}{2^{100}} \times (100!)^2$$

$\mathbf{\text{EXTENSION=}}$ I saw that you like to play with the question ,so i wrote this extension. What if "She does not have to put a sock on foot i before putting a shoe on foot " and the socks and shoes are distinguishable , what would happen ? (try this by yourself and write the answer in comment section)

Comment: I think that in that case, there would be $200!$ ways to arrange socks and shoes since we don't care about putting a sock above the shoe. Then we should multiply this by the possible combinations of socks and shoes, which is $(100!)^2$. So that would be $200!*(100!)^2$. Correct?

Comment: @Marco yeap  ,you got it !!

Comment: Thanks for the explaination!

Comment: @Marco you are welcome..